# How to stop an IntentService?

Tags: android, service, download

I use an IntentService to handle large file-downloads in my app. But when i want to cancel the download i call `stopService(intent)`. However the `onDestroy()` method is been called but the download doesn't stop.
What else do i have to do to cancel the download?
Thanks.

Comment: you must work with singleton instances and look for a handler message to stop your download.

Comment: could you give me a little more? i dont really know what i should do with this.

Answer (score 8):

I have not figured this out myself, but I send an `Intent` with:

```
intent.putExtra("pause", "yes");
startService(intent);
```

And then I override `public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int a, int b)` inside the `IntentService` (which is not recommended) and seeing that "pause" is "yes" I set a static boolean `mPaused` to `true`. If you have a loop in `onHandleIntent`, add `&& !mPaused` in the loop condition.

Of course this is all 'bad' code and a hack... but I hope somebody else chimes in with the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Not a bad code, I think. This is a properly way to pause a service.